# How to add text in stacked area chart in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I want to add the text of cities names from the city column of my data.

In the image below I have added text as I want it to appear. How can I add the text automatically?

[image: Chart with text]

Comment: Here is the code and libraries for "LineChart.html", you just need to download and run on browser.

Comment: Did you mean to attach some files? It would be easiest if you could use codepen or jsFiddle to share your work. Also, where do you expect the text to be added? The Y coordinate is obvious but I'm not clear where the text should be placed in the X dimension.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for response, I added my code on codepen you can access here https://codepen.io/vchouksey/project/editor/XwKbMe/

Comment: Thanks, but how should the text be placed? I don't see any reference to cities in your data; where does that data come from and why is orange necessarily associated with Berlin, Amsterdam and Panama with blue?

Comment: var text = [{total: "Berlin", tip: "Amsterdam", tip: "Panama"}]  where total and Tip are fields in dataset, Blue and Orange area is just show changes in value of total and tip, so we need to place value where we find enough space in Orange and blue area, position does not matter.

Comment: You can't really mean that. Why would you label something if you don't care where the labels go? When you originally asked by email, you referred to a streamgraph. In a streamgraph, the labels refer to the areas.

Comment: Users(investigation agencies) is more comfortable with stacked Area chart, they wants to see value inside each area, I also added legend but they are not satisfied customer wants to see value written inside stack area, Users are from non technical background,

Comment: So you are labeling the stacks - with this example the proper labels would be "tip" and "total spend".

Comment: Yes, in addition I am also trying to add values related to labels for example [{total: "Berlin", tip: "Amsterdam", tip: "Panama"}].

Comment: That's not proper javascript so I'm not sure what you mean (two values for the same key).

Comment: Yes, you are correct it should be like this                                  {total: "Berlin", tip: ["Amsterdam", "Panama"]}

Comment: Sorry, but that still doesn't make sense. I can understand labeling the stacks fine, but why would a stack have different names? And surely if it did have different names, the X position of those names would matter. Please think this through more carefully, find an example that is closer to what you are actually trying to do, and then edit your question, because this conversation is getting long and that makes the question less helpful to future readers.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TFzf.png , It has some tooltip-like labels shown by default, without any user interaction needed to get an 
overview of the content of the topics. It also includes a legend on the left. this is most closely resembling example that I want to achieve in stacked are chart.

Comment: Those look manually placed to me, I don't see any rule to it. At least in a streamgraph are one per "stack" so I could imagine some automated algorithm. But on top of that your seem to want multiple labels per stack and that's where I give up because arbitrary placement just seems wrong. What if Amsterdam and Panama were reversed in your example above, would that make as much sense?

Comment: No, because person is in Amsterdam total spend 100 bucks in between 0 to 05:30 PM time interval, where as that person is now in panama total spend 100 bucks again but time interval is 06:15 to 06:25.


In Nutshell, based on Datetime interval and y-axis values(transaction spend) we need to show event's entities without user interaction, in our case its city (amsterdam, Panama, Berlin),

Comment: And earlier you said "position does not matter". These "people" are not in your sample code or data. Sorry, I'm out of here. Define your problem properly or do not expect help.

Comment: I am sorry Gordon I should have asked you properly early, I updated my code and Data here https://codepen.io/vchouksey/project/editor/XwKbMe/, 
Now ruling is: Using Time, Total Spend and Tip value we need to show city name in stack.